# Using GPS data for vehicle tracking where there are no cellular services

Tags: gps, tracking, gsm, gprs

I am working on a project that deals with GPS based tracking of vehicles. I want to know if we can use GPS data for real time tracking of vehicles in areas where there are no cellular services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, GPS works everywhere in the world, when you have free view to sky.
It does not work in tunnels, underground and indoors.
Without cellular service the phone needs some seconds more to get the first valid GPS position after enabling it.